# In Java Apache Derby Database getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 53?

Tags: java, database, derby

I am getting error while creating table in derby db Please help .

first i am searching if the table is present in the database if not i am creating the table but i am getting and wierd exception this same query is working fine in Oracle local database.

```
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
            String dbName = "ServerDetails";
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true";
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            //PreparedStatement createPS = null;
            ResultSet createRS = null;


            //String checkQuery = "select * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE table_name like UPPER('XX_SERVER_DETAILS')";
            String tableScript = "CREATE TABLE XX_SERVER_DETAILS"
                    + "("
                    + "  USERNAME1  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,"
                    + "  PASSWORD1  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,"
                    + "  SERVER1    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,"
                    + "  USERNAME2  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,"
                    + "  PASSWORD2  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,"
                    + "  SERVER2    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                  NOT NULL"
                    + ")";

            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
            rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, "XX_SERVER_DETAILS",null);

            if(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Table "+rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")+"already exists !!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Write your create table function here !!!");
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(tableScript);
                createRS = ps.executeQuery();
                //createPS = conn.prepareStatement(tableScript);
                //createRS = createPS.executeQuery();
                conn.commit();
                ps.close();
                rs.close();
                //createPS.close();
                //createRS.close();
            }
```

Stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 53.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at persistencetier.DatabaseConn.server_Connection(DatabaseConn.java:157)
    at presentationtier.InstanceController.<init>(InstanceController.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:736)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:780)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:185)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:568)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2356)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2172)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2830)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)
    at presentationtier.StartController.aolAction(StartController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1451)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6866)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3369)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3209)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1582)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 53.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 53.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 86 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake Sorry for posting the Question the Script will be Something like this

```
    String tableScript = "CREATE TABLE XX_SERVER_DETAILS"
            + "("
            + "  USERNAME1  VARCHAR(10)                  NOT NULL,"
            + "  PASSWORD1  VARCHAR(10)                  NOT NULL,"
            + "  SERVER1    VARCHAR(50)                  NOT NULL,"
            + "  USERNAME2  VARCHAR(10)                  NOT NULL,"
            + "  PASSWORD2  VARCHAR(10)                  NOT NULL,"
            + "  SERVER2    VARCHAR(50)                  NOT NULL"
            + ")";
```

Derby doesnot accept varchar2 .and as i was reusing query of oracle it gave the error.